# How to make tiny size barcode using Free 3 of 9

Tags: c#, barcode

```
public class Barcode
    {
        public Bitmap CreateBarcode(string data)
        {
            string barcodeData = "*" + data + "*";
            Bitmap barcode = new Bitmap(1, 1);
            // less than size 40, my barcode reader can not read it.
            Font threeOfNine = new Font("Free 3 of 9", 40,
                                        System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                                        System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);

            Font arial = new Font("Arial", 15,
                                  System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                                  System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);

            Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode);
            SizeF dataSize = graphics.MeasureString(barcodeData, threeOfNine);
            dataSize.Height = 70;

            barcode = new Bitmap(barcode, dataSize.ToSize());
            graphics = Graphics.FromImage(barcode);

            graphics.Clear(Color.White);
            graphics.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.SingleBitPerPixel;

            graphics.DrawString(barcodeData, threeOfNine, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 0, 0);

            graphics.DrawString(data, arial, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), 50, 40);

            graphics.Flush();

            threeOfNine.Dispose();
            graphics.Dispose();

            return barcode;
        }
    }
```

I am using the above code to generate barcode using Free 3 of 9. but If I see the size less than 40, my barcode reader can not read that code. The size 40 is too big for my application, is there any way to reduce the barcode size?

```
Font threeOfNine = new Font("Free 3 of 9", 30,
                            System.Drawing.FontStyle.Regular,
                            System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit.Point);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a barcode to be scanned correctly, one of two conditions must apply:

- The width of every barcode feature, in device pixels, must be large
- The width of every barcode feature, in device pixels, must be an exact integer

If one renders a code 39 barcode with a base feature width of 1/72" and tries to print it on a 101.6dpi device, some features which are supposed to be 1/72" wide will print as one pixel wide and others as two pixels.  Features which are supposed to be 2/72" will mostly print as three pixels wide, but sometimes as two.  A scanner which sees something two pixels wide won't be able to know whether it's a wide feature which got printed narrower than usual, or a narrow feature which got printed wider than usual.

If the barcode size were shrunk to match the resolution of the output device, then things which were two pixels wide would appear to the scanner twice as big as those which were one pixel wide.  Even though the barcodes would be smaller, they'd be much more likely to be readable.  Alternatively, if the output device resolution were increased (e.g. to 300dpi) then single-width features would be 4-5 pixels, while double-width features would be 8-9 pixels.  Even if a narrow feature which printed as 5 pixels wide was followed by a wide feature that printed as 8 (a size ratio somewhat below the "correct" 2:1), a scanner should have no trouble reading it.

Note that while some formats only use two widths of bars and spaces, others like Code 128 use more.  Reliable scanning requires that one be able to distinguish single, double, triple, and quad-width features.  If single-width features are between 3 and 4 pixels wide (so they sometimes appear as 3 and sometimes as 4) a scanner may have difficulty determining whether a feature that was printed as 12 pixels wide is a triple-width feature that printed wider than nominal, or a quad-width feature that was narrower.  Most scanners could probably make the inferences necessary to figure it out, but having consistent widths for single, double, triple, and quad-width features would greatly improve readability.